# Safe repair of damaged wire insulation in switch box

Tags: electrical

While changing out a switch and surface mount electrical box, I abraded away a little of the insulation on the hot wire coming into the box. This happened when I was using needle nose pliers to pull the wire through the opening in the new box.

For now, I have wrapped the area in electrical tape.  Is that a safe repair?  Would heat shrink tubing over the area be a better repair?  Should I cut out the damaged part and do an extra splice in the box?

Thanks

Comment: How about a picture of the damage.

Answer (score 1):

### Electrical tape and *listed* heatshrink are both options here

You can use either a UL listed electrical tape or UL listed heavy-wall heatshrink for this, as both are listed to insulated splices and joints in electrical wires, where they must provide a complete replacement for the insulation on the wires being joined.  Note that most heatshrink tubing is *not* UL listed (it's Rather Useless to us, aka a UL recognized component, due to having thinner/less abuse-resistant walls).

Comment: A quick search finds some 3M UL listed. But normally purchased in large packages. A pack of electrical tape is cheaper/easier for occasional minor repairs.

Comment: Some heat shrink is listed usually the type with adhesive/ sealing agent on the inside most small diameter are 300v listed and larger sizes are usually 600v listed. Heat shrink is far superior to even the highest quality electrical tape as even super88 takes proper technique and even then proper heat shrink is a better choice as it won’t unravel over time as can happen on a single small diameter conductor.